# sed bash substitution only if variable has a value

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to find a way using variables and sed to do a specific text substitution using a changing input file, but only if there is a value given to replace the existing string with. No value= do nothing (rather than remove the existing string).

Example
Substitute.csv contains 5 lines=

```
this-has-text
this-has-text

this-has-text
this-has-text
```

and file.text has one sentence=

```
"When trying this I want to be sure that text-this-has is left alone."
```

If I run the following command in a shell script

```
Text='text-this-has'
Change=`sed -n '3p' substitute.csv`
grep -rl $Text /home/username/file.txt | xargs sed -i "s|$Text|$Change|"
```

I end up with

```
"When trying this I want to be sure that is left alone."
```

But I'd like it to remain as

```
"When trying this I want to be sure that text-this-has is left alone."
```

Any way to tell sed "If I give you nothing new, do nothing"?

---

I apologize for the overthinking, bad habit. Essentially what I'd like to accomplish is if line 3 of the csv file has a value - replace $Text with $Change inline. If the line is empty, leave $Text as $Text.

Comment: check if `$Change` is empty before going to `sed`?

Comment: Wow, you made that question WAY more complicated than it has to be! All of that stuff about reading the third line from a file and greps piped to xargs is completely irrelevant and so wastes our time trying to understand it all and obfuscates the very simple question.

Answer (score 4):

```
Text='text-this-has'
Change=$(sed -n '3p' substitute.csv)
if [[ -n $Change ]]; then
    grep -rl $Text /home/username/file.txt | xargs sed -i "s|$Text|$Change|"
fi
```

Comment: ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: Tried it and forgot to put the correct path instead of the example path. Worked Perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Just keep it simple and use awk:

```
awk -v t="$Text" -v c="$Change" 'c!=""{sub(t,c)} {print}' file
```

If you need inplace editing just use GNU awk with `-i inplace`.

Given your clarified requirement, this is probably what you actually want:

```
awk -v t="$Text" 'NR==FNR{if (NR==3) c=$0; next} c!=""{sub(t,c)} {print}' Substitute.csv file.txt
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this approach. I'm just starting to get familiar with sed and haven't tackled awk yet. I'd like to replace the text inline and move on to the next command. Could you provide an example of implementing gawk to do that. I've tried a couple methods that I thought would be correct, but no luck.

Comment: @user2416772 sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else you should use awk. I don't understand your request though - please edit your original question to show sample input and expected output for your new requirement or accept an answer here and post a new question.

Comment: @jaypal no worries, everyone remembers the guy who almost wrote `E=MC2`.. Oh, wait.... :-).

Answer (score 2):

Testing whether `$Change` has a value before launching into the `grep` and `sed` is undoubtedly the most efficient bash solution, although I'm a bit skeptical about the duplication of `grep` and `sed`; it saves a temporary file in the case of files which don't contain the target string, but at the cost of an extra scan up to the match in the case of files which do contain it.

If you're looking for typing efficiency, though, the following might be interesting:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i "s|$Text|${Change:-&}|" {} \;
```

Which will recursively find all files whose names end with the extension `.txt` and execute the `sed` command on each one. `${Change:-&}` means "the value of `$Change` if it exists and is non-empty, and otherwise an <kbd>&</kbd>"; & in the replacement of a `sed` `s` command means "the matched text", so `s|foo|&|` replaces every occurrence of `foo` with itself. That's an expensive no-op but if your time matters more than your cpu time, it might have been worth it.